# Iterating over children of a DataSnapshot throws exception

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to iterate over the children in a `DataSnapshot` it throws a `RangeError`. This is the code that I have:

```
  Map<String, Object> mapOfMaps(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, Object> map = <String, Object>{};

    for (var child in snapshot.children) {
      if (child.children.isNotEmpty) {
        map[child.key!] = mapOfMaps(child);
      } else {
        map[child.key!] = child.value!;
      }
    }

    return map;
  }
```

There are 7 children but the exception says: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..6: -1`. Why is it trying to start iterating at -1?

Based on the answer below I changed the code to this:

```
  Map<String, Object> mapOfMaps(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, Object> map = <String, Object>{};
    if (snapshot.children.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var child in snapshot.children) {
        if (child.children.isNotEmpty) {
          map[child.key!] = mapOfMaps(child);
        } else {
          map[child.key!] = child.value!;
        }
      }
    }
    return map;
  }
```

and I'm getting the same error. When I check the length before the error it's 7. The error happens on the iteration portion of the for loop.

Trying to use the iterator gives me the same error:

```
  Map<String, Object> mapOfMaps(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<String, Object> map = <String, Object>{};
    if (snapshot.exists && snapshot.children.isNotEmpty) {
      Iterator<DataSnapshot> itr = snapshot.children.iterator;
      while(itr.moveNext()) {
        DataSnapshot child = itr.current;
        if (child.children.isNotEmpty) {
          map[child.key!] = mapOfMaps(child);
        } else {
          map[child.key!] = child.value!;
        }
      }
    }
    return map;
  }
```

This only seems to fail on a DataSnapshot that is an array instead of a map. Firebase looks like it has given it integer keys and the type in the debug window is the same as all of the others so I don't know why it would fail there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that the problem was that one of the children was a List and not a Map so when I tried to iterate over the keys there's weren't any. Here's the code that I have that works now:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = <String, Object>{};
if (exists && children.isNotEmpty) {
  map["id"] = key!;
  for (var child in children) {
    if (child.value.runtimeType == List) {
      map[child.key!] = child.value!;
    } else if (child.value.runtimeType == Map) {
      map[child.key!] = child.toMap();
    } else {
      map[child.key!] = child.value!;
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```